# Is $argv in fish shell different from $@ in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, fish

I was trying to learn and write some fish scripts, but I encountered a strange issue.

```
# a.fish
# this is a fish script 
set temp (getopt -o abc -l ace,bad,correct -- $argv)
echo $temp
```

When I ran `fish ./a.fish -a -b --correct` it worked fine and output

```
-a -b --correct --
```

However, when I changed the `$argv` to `"$argv"` and ran it again, I got this
[image: issue]

Then I wrote a bash script

```
# a.sh
temp=$(getopt -o abc -l ace,bad,correct -- $@)
echo $temp
```

and ran it with `bash ./a.sh -a -b --correct`. Worked fine. After I added `"` around `$@` it still worked fine!

So here comes the question:

What's the difference between `$argv` and `$@` (or maybe I should ask whether fish and bash handle variables differently?)

I thought it was just simple replacement but this confused me. Can somebody help me? Any help will be appreciated :)

OS: ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, different shells are different. `strace` as always can help show what exactly is sent through an `execve(2)` call.

```
$ cat fecho
/usr/bin/echo $argv
$ cat fechoquoted 
/usr/bin/echo "$argv"
$ fish ./fecho a b c
a b c
$ fish ./fechoquoted a b c
a b c
$
```

Yet these two are actually rather different under the `strace`-scope:

```
$ strace -qq -f -e trace=execve fish ./fecho a b c
execve("/usr/bin/fish", ["fish", "./fecho", "a", "b", "c"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
[pid 15532] execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["/usr/bin/echo", "a", "b", "c"], [/* 21 vars */]) = 0
a b c
$ strace -qq -f -e trace=execve fish ./fechoquoted a b c
execve("/usr/bin/fish", ["fish", "./fechoquoted", "a", "b", "c"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
[pid 15542] execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["/usr/bin/echo", "a b c"], [/* 21 vars */]) = 0
a b c
$
```

The first passes a list of arguments to `echo` ("a", "b", "c"), and the second a single list item ("a b c"). So in your `getopt` case, when quoted as "$argv" the arguments are passed to `getopt(1)` as a single string, not as a list of individual elements, and `getopt(1)` fails as it wants a list of items, not a single string.

A `strace` on `bash` should show what `"$@"` does; one hypothesis would be that it splits the elements out to a list instead of smushing them together as a single item.

Comment: yes, just as you said, bash splits the ```“$@"```  to a list. I just searched the manpage of bash and found that at around ```27%```  .